# Mystery of subsite types

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell

I can not figure out what types should go in my `Foundation.hs` when implementing type classes from the authentication plugin / it's use of the auth subsite:

I can feel that I am very close, but I lack understanding. I am simply trying to use a different layout for the login/registration pages.

In Foundation.hs:

```
instance YesodAuthSimple App where
    type AuthSimpleId App = UserId

    ...

    -- Works
    onRegisterSuccess :: YesodAuthSimple site => AuthHandler site Html
    onRegisterSuccess = authLayout $ [whamlet|
      $newline never
      <div>
        <h1>You Registered successfully.
        <p>
          Some text here.
    |]  

    -- Works when I do not write a type signature
    loginTemplate toParent mErr = $(widgetFile "authpartials/login")


    -- Does not work with or without type signatures
    customAuthLayout widget = do 
        master <- getYesod
        mmsg <- getMessage
        muser <- maybeAuthPair
        mcurrentRoute <- getCurrentRoute
        pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
            $(widgetFile "custom-auth-layout")
        withUrlRenderer $(hamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```

The 432:15 is referring to the `widgetToPageContent` call.

In the type class definition Simple.hs:

```
class (YesodAuth site, PathPiece (AuthSimpleId site)) => YesodAuthSimple site where
  type AuthSimpleId site

  ...

  customAuthLayout :: WidgetFor site () -> AuthHandler site Html

  ...
```

I pasted in the definition of `customAuthLayout` from `defaultLayout` from Foundation.hs

Here is the error I get from GHC:

```
Foundation.hs:432:15: error:
    • Could not deduce: m ~ HandlerFor App
      from the context: MonadAuthHandler App m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   customAuthLayout :: WidgetFor App () -> AuthHandler App Html
        at src/Foundation.hs:(427,5)-(434,79)
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          customAuthLayout :: WidgetFor App () -> AuthHandler App Html
        at src/Foundation.hs:(427,5)-(434,79)
      Expected type: m (PageContent (Route App))
        Actual type: HandlerFor App (PageContent (Route App))
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        pc <- widgetToPageContent
                $ do (do do (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
                              ((blaze-markup-0.8.2.2:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText
                                  GHC.Base.. Data.Text.pack)
                                 "<!--  custom-auth-layout -->
<body class="d-flex align-items-center bg-auth border-top border-top-2 border-primary">")
                            ....)
      In the expression:
        do master <- getYesod
           mmsg <- getMessage
           muser <- maybeAuthPair
           mcurrentRoute <- getCurrentRoute
           ....
      In an equation for ‘customAuthLayout’:
          customAuthLayout widget
            = do master <- getYesod
                 mmsg <- getMessage
                 muser <- maybeAuthPair
                 ....
    |
432 |         pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

I have used this tutorial successfully for normal (non-subsite pages) https://ersocon.net/cookbooks/yesod/html-and-seo/custom-layouts

But I am getting tripped up by the subsite types. I have read Michael Snoyman's very good old blog post on subsite types but I cannot understand GHC's error message.

I suspect either the type signature in Simple.hs is wrong, or I am missing something from the function definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `liftHandler` before `widgetToPageContent`:

```
...
pc <- liftHandler $ widgetToPageContent $ do
    $(widgetFile "custom-auth-layout")
...
```

Key lines in the error message are:

```
  Could not deduce: m ~ HandlerFor App
  ...
  Expected type: m (PageContent (Route App))
    Actual type: HandlerFor App (PageContent (Route App))
```

It is basically telling us that it expected a more generic type `m`, but instead it got a `HandlerFor App`. So the solution is simply to *lift* the call to `widgetToPageContent` using the `liftHandler` function.

To elaborate further, if we look at the type signature of the function [`widgetToPageContent`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.12/yesod-core-1.6.16.1/Yesod-Core.html#v:widgetToPageContent), we see that it returns `HandlerFor site (PageContent (Route site))`. In this case, `site` instantiates to `App`, and that is the `HandlerFor App (PageContent (Route App))` you see in the error message.

Similarly, your `customLayout` function returns `AuthHandler site Html`. [`AuthHandler`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.12/yesod-auth-1.6.8/Yesod-Auth.html#t:AuthHandler) is just a type synonym that constrains `site` to a type equivalent to `HandlerSite m` which is also an instance of `YesodAuth`. This also resolves to `App`, and that is why we get `MonadAuthHandler App m` and `m (PageContent (Route App))` in the error message.

Comment: This is a great and detailed answer, this worked, my thanks to you @alexandre-lucchesi

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped. :)